# she missed the test as she was not feeling well

Tags: syntactic-analysis

This is the complex sentence:

**I went to market because Adam gave me the loan.**

What will be the simple sentence of the above complex sentence?

I am trying:

**I went to market because of the Adam's loan.**

It is somehow correct but **gave me** is omitted. How to make simple sentence including those two words?

It is required because I am going to make new section here -
https://englishact.com/EnglishGrammar/

Comment: Asif, if that's a serious Question why not try asking it somewehre such as English Language Learners, please?

As it is, you're mixing up too many things in an example that could never clearly work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two simple sentences: *Adam gave me a loan. I went to market.*

As Jason mentioned, if you have more than one clause it's still a complex sentence. There are different ways to express the same (or similar) meaning, but you have two different statements ("I went to market" and "Adam gave me a loan") that you need to pack into it. You could perhaps nominalise one of them -- it's easier to turn the first one into a noun phrase (*Adam's loan*), but that invariably means you lose the *gave me* which you want to keep. And *Adam gave me the loan to go to market* is still a complex sentence.

Possible options without *gave me* are:

- *Adam's loan enabled me to go to market.*
- *Because of Adam's loan I could go to market.*
- *Going to market was made possible by Adam's loan.*

PS: In your example *because of the Adam's loan* is incorrect: you should not use the determiner *the* before a proper name in that context.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the term [complex sentence](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/wrtps/index-eng.html?lang=eng&lettr=indx_catlog_c&page=95X9nuoZVkVo.html) to mean "a sentence that contains one independent clause and one or more dependent clauses," then both of your sentences are complex.

The most direct way of turning your sentence into a [simple sentence](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/wrtps/index-eng.html?lang=eng&lettr=indx_catlog_s&page=9UZr1RczweZ4.html) (having only one clause) is:

> I went to market.

Note, however, that this leaves out information.